# elasticsearch multiple aggregation on time interval

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello Elasticsearch folks,

I am trying to perform a time-based query on a time series dataset stored in elasticsearch.

I wonder if anybody may share some tricks to do things like this...
Basically, every document comes with UTC time and a value. Ultimately, I want to find out the average value for every hour through the day for last 12 month.

My current approach is kinda hacky - I store data in hourly basis and also stored a field as the hour of the day, i.e 1 PM UTC is 13. But it is so hacky and comes with series of problem:
1. It doesn't have daylight saving adjustment as you may already notice.
2. I kinda have to convert UTC hours of the day back to the local time of Day.
3. many other issues....

Greatly appreciated for your help in advance!

Leon

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should give you what you need without any hacks:

```
{
  "query": {},
  "aggs": {
    "hourOfDay": {
      "histogram": {
        "script": "doc['timestamp'].date.getHourOfDay()",
        "interval": 1,
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 23
        },
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Or.
What if the dynamic script is not available? Also, I probably need to do the timezone conversion before aggregation is done.